# Can not Insert record into mysql table with php prepared-statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-insert

my code partially works in **`ELSE`** part below. What I mean partially is **it doesn't INSERT INTO table** but since all verification stages are correct, **it redirects to thanks page.**
What I normally expect is both. Insert into table **A N D** then go to thanks page.
I thought my situation is about the prepared statement so I studied http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php but I couldn't solve my case. I am getting **NO** notice, warning or error. but my table is still empty. Can you help with my fault(s) please?
Thanks
BR

```
    header( "HTTP/1.1 303 See Other" );

if ($_SESSION['hatalar'] != '')
{
    $sonraki_sayfa = sitenin_koku.'yazılar/'.$_SESSION['spesifik_yazi_url'];
    header('Location: ' . $sonraki_sayfa);
}
else //verification passed. save the comment + redirect to thanks page.
{
    /* YORUMU TABLOYA YAZDIRALIM  */
    $sorgum = "INSERT INTO tb_yorumlar (kolon_yorumcu_isim, kolon_statu, kolon_yorum, kolon_hangi_yazara, kolon_hangi_basliga, kolon_yorum_tarihi, kolon_ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)";

    if ($beyan = $db_baglanti->prepare($sorgum)) 
        {
            /* give their values to parameters  */ 
            $bindparametre1 = $_POST['yf-isim'];
            $bindparametre2 = 'onay';
            $bindparametre3 = $_POST['yf-mesaj'];
            $bindparametre4 = $_SESSION['spesifik_yazi_yazar'];
            $bindparametre5 = $_SESSION['spesifik_yazi_baslik'];
            $bindparametre6 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            /* bind parameters */
            if (!$beyan -> bind_param("ssssss", $bindparametre1, $bindparametre2, $bindparametre3, $bindparametre4, $bindparametre5, $bindparametre6))
            {echo "parametre atama hatası: (" . $beyan->errno . ") " . $beyan->error;}

            /* execute statement */
            if (!$beyan->execute())
            {echo "Gerçekleştirme hatası: (" . $beyan->errno . ") " . $beyan->error ;}
        }
    else {echo "Hazırlama hatası: (" . $db_baglanti->errno . ") " . $db_baglanti->error;}

    /* TEŞEKKÜR SAYFASINA YÖNLENDİRELİM */
    $sonraki_sayfa = sitenin_koku.'yorumunuz-için-teşekkür-ederim';
    header('Location: ' . $sonraki_sayfa);

}
```

Comment: What is the structure of the table you're inserting into

Comment: is there any short sql command to paste the result because my table is a little bit long to write

Comment: Are you sure the variables are all being assigned values?

Comment: I couldn't understand. If not assigned, then how can I insert the specific right values

Comment: Check my answer - I think you may be dealing with some null values here. The code looks fine.

Comment: I was just looking for the structure of your table, not all of its data. For example `(table_name(String, string, int ... etc.))` I'm curious to see whether or not the variables you're using of are the right type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would comment out the header location part (see below) and echo out the values - make sure that the values you're inserting are actually filled (not null).

```
if ($beyan = $db_baglanti->prepare($sorgum)) {
    /* give their values to parameters  */
    $bindparametre1 = $_POST['yf-isim'];
    $bindparametre2 = 'onay';
    $bindparametre3 = $_POST['yf-mesaj'];
    $bindparametre4 = $_SESSION['spesifik_yazi_yazar'];
    $bindparametre5 = $_SESSION['spesifik_yazi_baslik'];
    $bindparametre6 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if (!$beyan->bind_param("ssssss", $bindparametre1, $bindparametre2, $bindparametre3, $bindparametre4, $bindparametre5, $bindparametre6)) {
        echo "parametre atama hatas?: (" . $beyan->errno . ") " . $beyan->error;
    }

    if (!$beyan->execute()) {
        echo "Gerçekles,tirme hatas?: (" . $beyan->errno . ") " . $beyan->error ;
    }
}
else {
    echo "Haz?rlama hatas?: (" . $db_baglanti->errno . ") " . $db_baglanti->error;
}

/* TES,EKKÜR SAYFASINA YÖNLENDI.RELI.M */
$sonraki_sayfa = sitenin_koku.'yorumunuz-için-tes,ekkür-ederim';
//header('Location: ' . $sonraki_sayfa);

echo $bindparametre1 . "<br>";
echo $bindparametre2 . "<br>";
echo $bindparametre3  . "<br>";
echo $bindparametre4  . "<br>";
echo $bindparametre5  . "<br>";
echo $bindparametre6  . "<br>";
```

Comment: after I tried, 2 notices and 1 error. Error is (1048) Column 'kolon_hangi_yazara' cannot be null. AND 2 notices=> notice 1: Undefined index: spesifik_yazi_yazar in ... on line 85 . Notice 2: Undefined index: spesifik_yazi_baslik in ... on line 86

Comment: @AndreChenier Make sure you add `session_start()` to the top of any PHP page where you want to use `$_SESSION` variables

Comment: it is strange because I already started session. If I again add top of page the session_start(), page gives Notice: A session had already been started.

Comment: @AndreChenier Right, you don't want it more than once. I was just making sure you had it. So, it seems as though you have some null parameters (that is what I had thought). Go back to your other pages and make sure your SESSION vars are being set properly

Comment: so I have to find out why my session variables are null. Thank you Evan.

Comment: @AndreChenier Yes sir, that is the issue here. The session variables are not even set. You should check if they are set by using the `isset` function in PHP (google that)